# create a graphdef from inceptionV3 model

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph

I have the following code to try to save graphdef file with a frozen graph, but its not working, error message : AssertionError: dense_1/Sigmoid is not in graph. Do you have idea how to fix that, or anything?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util

# Load the saved Keras model
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model_inception.5h')

# Get the names of the input and output nodes
input_name = model.inputs[0].name.split(':')[0]
output_names = [output.name.split(':')[0] for output in model.outputs]

# Convert the Keras model to a GraphDef
graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
    sess=tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.get_session(),
    input_graph_def=tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.get_session().graph.as_graph_def(),
    output_node_names=output_names)

# Freeze the GraphDef
frozen_graph_def = tf.compat.v1.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
    sess=tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.get_session(),
    input_graph_def=graph_def,
    output_node_names=output_names)

# Save the frozen GraphDef to a file
with open('frozen_graph.pb', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(frozen_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Indentation is important in `python`.